# Entidades classes

Tags: modelagem, entidade-relacionamento, diagrama

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de venda ao qual vou ter cadastrado um `funcionário` que possa ser também um `vendedor`, vou ter um `cliente` que pode ser uma `pessoa física` ou `pessoa jurídica`, `fornecedores` que podem ser `pessoa jurídica`. A regra é que vou ter uma `proposta` comercial ao qual será vinculada a um `cliente`.

Ao final vou ter uma `venda` que vai ter como obrigatoriedade um `cliente`, um `vendedor` e uma `proposta`.

Criei uma entidade `pessoa` ao qual poderia ser utilizada como `cliente`, `fornecedor` e `funcionário`. Mas e em relação ao cliente, fica a minha dúvida, será necessário realmente ter uma entidade `cliente`? Quando adicionei ela foi pensando que uma `venda` não pode ter uma `pessoa`, porque uma `pessoa` pode ser `fornecedor` e `funcionário` e não um `cliente` caso a entidade não existir.

[image: DER]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 5):

Está indo no caminho correto. Me questiono se deveria ter `Pessoa`. Isso abstratamente é legal, mas fisicamente não acho que deveria ter, quase sempre isto é um erro e em banco de dados só fará perder performance. Claro, pode fazer assim, até porque conceitualmente não há nada errado, só não acho boa ideia.

Não conheço esta notação mas tem 3 formas de relacionamento e não entendo o que quer dizer duas delas, não parecem ser relacionamentos.

Eu não posso afirmar se precisa do `Cliente` ou não, se for só para ter um `id` não precisa, mas aí vale para `Funcionario` e `Vendedor` também. E não sei se vincularia `Vendedor` a `Funcionario`, um dia pode ter um `Vendedor` que não trabalha lá, ou até mesmo que seja pessoa jurídica. É melhor desvincular isso.

Comment: Verdade, posso ter um **vendedor** que seja representante. O **cliente** é apenas para eu identificar fisicamente no banco um cliente entre várias **pessoas**, pessoas que podem ser fornecedores ou  funcionários. Eu pensei em remover essa entidade cliente, mas não vejo outra forma de relacionar as minhas propostas  com uma pessoa.

Comment: Se for só isso mesmo eu não vejo como não poderia vincular diretamente. É que é quase certo que terão outras coisas específicas de cliente.

Comment: Duas dúvidas: 1) Se Vendedor é um papel de Funcionário, por que 1 funcionário para n vendedores? Não deveria ser 1 para 1? Mesma coisa para Pessoa e Cliente (1 pessoa para n clientes). 2) Por que no banco o Pessoa fará perder performance?

Comment: Eu acho que `Vendedor` é uma papel, não necessariamente de `Funcionario`, mas tem razão que em condições normais seria 1:1. Pode haver alguma situação que não seja, mas bem estranha. Tendo `Pessoa` também, são duas tabelas para consultar, a geral e a mais específica, ganho de organização quase zero, e que na prática é muito raro precisa sozinho. Pode até dizer que ter `Cliente`, `Fornecedor`, etc.  vale o mesmo. Mas este é um caso que organiza muito mais, porque é um papel,em muitos casos não precisará pegar 2 tabelas (o papel e a entidade) e pode ter vários papeis ao mesmo tempo,`Pessoa` só 1

Comment: Pelo que vi Funcionário estende PessoaFísica. Seria errado modelá-lo ao invés como papel de PessoaFísica? Só que aí Vendedor seria papel do papel :)

Comment: @Piovezan eu acho que sim, esse é um caso que não cabe um papel. Mas falar que jamais deva fazer isso eu não digo.

Comment: @Maniero Só para eu entender melhor, por que nesse caso não cabe o papel?

Comment: Porque não é um papel, na minha visão, alguém poderia contestar, eu consigo ter uma visão que é sim. Afinal `Pessoa` é uma pessoa, e ser `Física` ou `Jurídica` é só uma condição dela. Mas eu prefiro ver que a pessoa pu é física ou jurídica, não pode ser ambos. Quando é excludente não faz sentido ter papéis. Aí cabe um `é um`, e não um `tem um`. Por isso não gosto desses nomes de relações desse DER, mas não os questiono. Ser gera herança, ter gera composição.