# Funcionário pode ser papel de Pessoa Física?

Tags: modelagem, entidade-relacionamento, diagrama, der

Foi recomendado, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313506/entidades-classes), manter a relação entre `Pessoa Física` e `Funcionário` como generalização (Funcionário estende Pessoa Física).

Não entendi por que não cabe nesse caso fazer uma relação de papel (Funcionário é papel de Pessoa Física), pelo menos da forma como entendo que papéis funcionam. Para não ficar tirando dúvidas nos comentários e gerar alguns pontos no sistema de Q&A, transformei em uma pergunta.

Uma justificativa pode ser que daí fica estranho a entidade `Vendedor` ser "papel de um papel", isto é, Vendedor ser papel do Funcionário, que por sua vez é papel de Pessoa Física. Mas gostaria de um esclarecimento maior.

Foi justificado que Pessoa Física é uma condição excludente (não pode ser física e jurídica ao mesmo tempo), e nesse caso não faz sentido ter papéis, mas não entendi bem essa justificativa. Não vejo mal em Pessoa Física ter um papel.

Comment: Usualmente pra mim o Funcionário é uma especialização (talvez o que vc chame de papel) de Pessoa física. Assim como Cliente é outra especialização, Usuário do sistema é mais uma especialização, e assim vai. Afinal, são pessoas, não? E todas as pessoas potencialmente podem ser quaisquer ou todas as especializações mencionadas. Sequer vejo confusão nisso, pra mim a modelagem é mera descrição formal da realidade.

Comment: Sobre a questão do excludente, vejo 2 maneiras mais óbvias. Ou você tem juridica e fisica, sem misturar, ou vc tem "entidades" e a pessoa juridica e pessoa fisica são especializações (o que não descarta que a física continue sendo tratada como eu mencionei no inicio). Eu tenho tendência a não misturar as 2 coisas (o que não significa não reaproveitar os relacionamentos nos pontos em comum, são coisas que podem ser administradas sem problema), mas ai é caso a caso.

Comment: Não chamo papel de especialização e sim um relacionamento Pessoa Física "tem papel de" ou "executa papel de" Funcionário. [Exemplo](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_09/column2/images/fig9.gif) de Empresa tendo papéis de Comprador, Vendedor, etc. (tirado [daqui](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_09/column2/)). É um relacionamento de composição.

Comment: Esses dos exemplos eu acho bem nonsense, pq eles inventam figuras desnecessárias (ou tem nomes ruins pras coisas). Não sei se o problema é nomenclatura, mas acho que fica extenso pra comentários. Infelizmente tem muita empresa grande e famosa que segue essa linha dos exemplos.

Comment: Tem na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_Class_Model) também (figura 3).

Comment: A da wikipedia tá bem melhor, usa "person". Salvo um "bot", um vendedor é realmente uma pessoa, um comprador tambem (pode ser juridica, ai cai no que eu falo da conveniencia pro seu caso), e um funcionario tb é pessoa. E essa pessoa pode ser todos simultaneamente. Mais do que modelagem, é fato. "Company role" pra mim nao carrega sentido nenhum. "Person" eu sei o que é sem precisar de explicação.

Comment: Concordo com tudo oque o Bacco falou até agora, mais tarde posso ver melhor.

Comment: Acha estranho o de Empresa? Eu deveria ter mostrado [essa figura](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2002_09/column2/images/fig6.gif), a outra só faz uma generalização sobre os papéis. Para mim é o mesmo relacionamento que em Person, "tem papel de", "pode agir como um". Relacionamento de composição. Não vê sentido no caso de Empresa também?

Comment: Eu nao consigo ver uma empresa se relacionando com um vendor, nem com um customer. Eu consigo ver uma company se relacionando com uma person com role de vendor e/ou customer. Essa ultima figura tá pulando a person.

Comment: Desculpe, acho que contextualizei errado pra você. No exemplo de Empresa é a própria empresa que está assumindo o papel de Vendor ou Customer. Ela (a empresa) é uma Vendedora ou Compradora de produtos.

Comment: Ah, mas ai ja saimos da sua pergunta. Até pode ter uma venda direta online etc, mas o assunto começa a ficar amplo se formos cobrir as possibilidades todas.

Comment: Tudo bem, só estou usando o exemplo que o artigo deu. Eu aprendi por ele. Podemos ficar no Person então. No Person você vê sentido. Faz sentido daí o Funcionário ser papel de Pessoa Física? Vou reler o que escreveu.

Comment: Certo. Eu não teria muito a acrescentar, só acho que realmente tem que pegar o seu problema real e resolver, desde que descreva bem a situação tá bom. Não tem receita mágica que sirva pra todos os casos, só princípios, creio eu. Os meus são de simplificar ao máximo e deixar autodescritivas as coisas (por isso que vc não vai me ver muito nas postagens com academicismo demais, eu acho a vida muito curta pra isso :D - penso que se tivesse receita boa que servisse pra tudo, já teria se consolidado, e se não tem, vamos resolver no caso real que é mais rápido)

Comment: Não vejo como academicismo a aplicação dos papéis, só estou com a dúvida se se aplicam a esse caso específico. Como em geral herança engessa muito as relações, pensei que composição nesse caso deixaria o design mais flexível (se tal relação couber conceitualmente).

Comment: _"E todas as pessoas potencialmente podem ser quaisquer ou todas as especializações mencionadas"_ (lá no primeiro comentário) não entendi, você está falando de herança múltipla?

Comment: @Bacco Ou de uma hierarquia com alguns níveis?

Comment: Oi, eu acho que é o que tem na resposta do @Maniero mesmo, entre herança e composição eu diria composição, mas já mencionei que eu procuro não me ater sobre a academicidade por isso mesmo. O mundo teórico é "muito legal", mas na hora o que vai mandar é o que a linguagem de fato tem e o que dá de recurso, então eu fujo dessas definições sempre que posso :)

Comment: Quem deu voto contra poderia justificar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Foi recomendado, nesta pergunta, manter a relação entre Pessoa Física e Funcionário como generalização (Funcionário estende Pessoa Física). Não entendi por que não cabe nesse caso fazer uma relação de papel (Funcionário é papel de Pessoa Física), pelo menos da forma como entendo que papéis funcionam.

Foi recomendado na pergunta, não na resposta. Eu acho um erro e disse que `Funcionario` é um papel de `PessoaFisica`. Até porque se essa pessoa também for um cliente e for uma especialização, portanto herança, a única solução é ter duas instâncias da mesma pessoa, o que é uma maluquice conceitual, ou guardar espaço na pessoa para ser tudo o que ela puder ser.

Pegando esse segundo caso tem duas formas de fazer: uma é manter tudo junto e a outra é ter referências externas.

Mantendo junto em memória só dá com enorme desperdício, e em DB, ou tem esse problema também, ou precisa de uma formato sem esquema, o que pode trazer outros problemas.

Mantendo separado em memória isso não é lá muito complicado, em um banco de dados é exatamente o que o modelo de papéis faz. É muito mais óbvio fazer assim, então não é herança de verdade, inclusive porque é algo dinâmico que o programador não tem controle.

A solução que as pessoas fazem é ter mais de uma pessoa entre os dados representando a pessoa pessoa real. É um erro crasso óbvio que "ninguém" vê.

Não pode fazer assim nunca? Pode, como otimização ou se realmente fizer sentido. Proibido nunca é.

Como otimização de acesso você pode manter nos papéis todos os dados da `Pessoa` para não ter que olhar mais de uma tabela, mas passa ter um custo de escrita (que pode ser vantajoso) já que qualquer alteração de dados na `Pessoa` tem que obrigatoriamente e de preferência atomicamente atualizar todos os papéis que aquela pessoa terá.

Um detalhe de implementação de [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) é que geralmente é mais interessante você ter uma mecanismo que indique quais papéis aquela pessoa possui ativamente. Isso pode ser algumas colunas (aí só com alteração programática para adicionar algum novo, e pode ter algum desperdício de espaço), pode ser *schemaless* com um "*array*" de papéis (nem todos DBs permitem facilmente), ou pode ter uma tabela extra que faça a amarração (custo muito caro de acesso). Na memória não é muito diferente, exceto que ela tem mais dificuldade de ser sem esquema sem uma tabela auxiliar, mas em compensação uma tabela extra custa barato neste dispositivo.

Papel é só uma simples composição, assim como você pode ter N vendas de um produto, você terá N papéis de uma pessoa. De fato o normal será N bem baixo, na maioria dos casos deve ser 1. É de se pensar o que compensa mais.

> Uma justificativa pode ser que daí fica estranho a entidade `Vendendor` ser "papel de um papel", isto é, Vendedor ser papel do Funcionário, que por sua vez é papel de Pessoa Física. Mas gostaria de um esclarecimento maior.

Exatamente, um papel ser ligado a um papel não faz sentido, quem tem o papel de `Vendedor`? A `Pessoa`. No caso pode ser física ou jurídica (mesmo que seu modelo nunca aceite isso quem garante que no futuro não aceitará?), já quebrou o modelo de `Vendedor` estar vinculado ao `Funcionario`. Mas se alguém disser que é diferente, ok, cada situação real pode pedir algo diferente.

Nos comentários tem um modelo de *roles* que não me agrada, não sei se é bem isso que eu chamo de papel. Mas pode ser só que esteja confuso para o que eu já sei. De qualquer forma tem exemplos bem ruins, cheio de coisas aparentemente desnecessários.

> Não vejo mal em Pessoa Física ter um papel

Eu também não.

O que eu disse foi que uma `PessoaFisica` não deveria ser uma papel de `Pessoa`. Mas fiz a ressalva que esta visão é válida em algum cenário.

Concretamente você, ou tem uma `PessoaFisica`, ou tem uma `PessoaJuridica`. `Pessoa` é naturalmente um conceito abstrato, que pode dar a impressão de não ser porque a gente tende acreditar que pessoa é um ser humano. Estamos falando de personalidade segundo a legislação. Não existe só `Pessoa`, do ponto de vista legal não tem esse objeto, ninguém é só isso, não tem descrições para o que seria esse objeto. Para física ou jurídica tem: relaciona os documentos necessários, um nome, endereço, sexo ou atividade, tem data de nascimento/fundação, etc.

Não cabe ter um papel em algo que sequer existe. Cabe ter um conceito concreto baseado em algo que pode ser generalizado. Na verdade em banco de dados relacionais é normal que `Pessoa` evapore quando se modela o físico. No máximo você terá uma *view* que permite acessar `PessoaFisica` ou `PessoaJuridica` sem distinção.

Mas está dito lá que não é o fim do mundo que tenha `Pessoa` concreta, só acho ineficiente para pouco ou nenhum benefício, você teria sempre que acessar duas tabelas para pegar tudo o que precisa na maioria dos casos. Esse é um caso que não tem o risco de ter uma mesma entidade sendo representada por dois objetos no *roll* dados manipulado. Papéis não são só bons, são necessários para não virar bagunça. O simples sempre deve ser preferível e nesse caso o simples é não ter papel. Quem quer complicar que deve justificar que problema ele quer resolver com a complicação.

Eu sei justificar o uso de papéis entre as pessoas concretas. Em parte é o que está aí em cima.

Eu tendo a não usar relações 1:1 no modelo (não confundir 1:1 nos dados), acho elas desnecessárias na maior parte dos casos, e onde costuma ser é pra resolver outro problema criado equivocadamente. Novamente, se acha que deve usar algo assim, tem que justificar.

Já viu a pergunta [Qual a vantagem de um relacionamento 1:1?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/253550/101)? Lá fala de 1:1 de dados e não de modelo, e se analisar bem, exceto pelo primeiro, todos os outros são por necessidades de mecanismos, não tem a ver com o modelo conceitual. Eu falo qual é o modelo ideal, se o mecanismo exige outra coisa faz parte de outro escopo.

Eu só me preocupo com isso porque sei a dificuldade que é mudar algo quando foi mal conceituado (e sempre fazemos isto, não tem como fazer perfeito sempre), e gosto de fazer otimizado. Se puder deixar de lado uma dessas coisas já importa menos, se puder deixar de lado ambos, aí tudo vale.

Como o Bacco disse nos comentários, modelagem tem que ser baseada em fatos. O problema é que muitos modelos são feitos em suposições, e visões da realidade que não são reais. E é fácil cair nessa armadilha. Eu vivo caindo em domínios que ainda não trabalhei, e mesmo nos que trabalhei geram alguns erros.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: _"Até porque se essa pessoa também for um cliente e for uma especialização, portanto herança, a única solução é ter duas instâncias da mesma pessoa, o que é uma maluquice conceitual, ou guardar espaço na pessoa para ser tudo o que ela puder ser."_ Não domino a transformação do conceitual para o físico, poderia esclarecer do que se tratam essas soluções?

Comment: Sim, e se esclarecer qual é a dúvida que eu não entendi.

Comment: Acho que nesse frase que citei está falando do conceitual, do modelo. Em seguida fala sobre como isso se converte em físico, em dados. Estou certo? A dúvida está aí, quando você diz _"a única solução é isso ou isso"_ eu não entendi o que são essas soluções.

Comment: Não exatamente, o conceitual é o foco, até falo do físico aplicando o conceitual, pq o físico é a aplicação do conceitual. Inclusive você acaba mudando o conceito se precisar fazer um físico diferente. Conceitual aí não é lógico. Até porque de nada adinata ter um lógico ótimo se o físico não encaixa.

Comment: "Ter duas instâncias da mesma pessoa" eu entendi mais ou menos o que é (mas explique mesmo assim se possível), agora "guardar espaço na pessoa" eu não entendi. Fala de ter atributos na entidade Pessoa? (posso falar do DER como se fosse um diagrama de classes? Os dois são parecidos). Se for isso, a dúvida é como isso se converte depois em dados.

Comment: Se você tiver uma pessoa que tem vários papéis nela mesma e só quer ter uma instância, qual é a solução? Ter uma pessoa que "saiba" tudo sobre os papéis, virar um objeto linguição com tudo lá. Os dados ficam tudo lá dentro. É horrível também.

Comment: Conceitual é diferente de lógico? "Rapaiz" do céu, vou lá estudar banco de dados, volto depois... :P

Comment: No sentido que estou falando é, conceitual é o que é, não falo de desenho no papel. Esse é o problema de criarem muito academicismo, começa ter termo demais, conceito de menos. Conceito é uma ideia geral, qualquer coisa que vá além disso não consigo ver propósito. Modelo lógico até vejo, mas pouco usado, porque ele é pouco necessário, e muitas vezes criar uam carga desnecessária pro projeto.