# Polimorfismo em Typescript

Tags: typescript, modelagem, herança, polimorfismo

Estou criando minha aplicação com a seguinte estrutura: Uma classe abstrata Pessoa, e herdando de Pessoa, as classes `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica`, E por fim, uma classe `Cliente` recebendo `Pessoa` como um atributo.

```
abstract class Pessoa {
    id?: number;
    nome?: string;
}

class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {
    public cpf?:string;
    public rg?:string;
    public sexo?:string;
    public profissao?: string;
    public data_nascimento?: Date

}

class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa{
    public razaoSocial?: string;
    public cnpj?: string;
    public ie?: string;
    public im?: string;
}

class Cliente{
    id?: number;
    pessoable?: Pessoa;

}
```

O problema esta sendo que quando instancio a classe desta forma:

```
let c:Cliente = new Cliente();
c.pessoable = new PessoaFisica();
```

Eu não consigo ter acesso no atributo `cpf`  utilizando `c.pessoable.cpf`. 
Onde estou errando?

Comment: `pessoable` é do tipo `Pessoa` que só tem duas propriedades `id` e `nome`. Para acessar o propriedade `cpf` do seu objeto `PessoaFisica` você tem fazer o type casting `(c as PessoaFisica).cpf ="000000000";` ou então `(<PessoaFisica> c).cpf ="000000000";`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## *Cast*

Até onde eu sei (pode ser que tenha uma solução que eu desconheço no TS) não tem solução boa, assim funciona:

```
abstract class Pessoa {
    id?: number;
    nome?: string;
}

class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {
    public cpf? : string;
    public rg? : string;
    public sexo? : string;
    public profissao? : string;
    public data_nascimento? : Date

}

class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa {
    public razaoSocial? : string;
    public cnpj? : string;
    public ie? : string;
    public im? : string;
}

class Cliente {
    id? : number;
    pessoable? : Pessoa;
}

let c : Cliente = new Cliente();
c.pessoable = new PessoaFisica();
let x = c.pessoable as PessoaFisica;
x.cpf = "123";
```

Só fazendo o *cast* o código tem acesso ao campo daquele tipo, porque foi declarado que `pessoable` (que nome feio) é do tipo `Pessoa` e este tipo não tem um campo chamado `cpf`. Mesmo que seja colocado um tipo concreto que exista para o compilador só vale o tipo explicitado na declaração. Fazendo o *cast* o tipo passa ser `PessoaFisica` e aí tem acesso so campo que deseja. E não vi uma forma de fazer tudo em um passo só.

Se fizer as devidas abstrações isso pode não ser tão feio porque esconderia essa "gambiarra" dentro da classe.

## Dois campos

Uma solução que poderia ser: ter dois campos um para cada tipo e aí usa só um deles conforme o tipo (no final vou mais fundo nessa ideia). Isso tem um outro problema de [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101), mas essa classe toda está cheia de vazamentos de abstração, por isso tudo é anulável.

Se a abstração for certa não é problema seu, consumidor da classe, saber que tem que fazer isso, você terá um meio de acessar esse dado de forma natural.

## Tipo genérico

Uma solução pouco melhor seria parametrizar o tipo porque afinal ou o cliente é pessoa física ou jurídica, não faz sentido aceitar os dois em campos separados ou juntos.

```
abstract class Pessoa {
    id?: number;
    nome?: string;
}

class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {
    public cpf? : string;
    public rg? : string;
    public sexo? : string;
    public profissao? : string;
    public data_nascimento? : Date

}

class PessoaJuridica extends Pessoa {
    public razaoSocial? : string;
    public cnpj? : string;
    public ie? : string;
    public im? : string;
}

class Cliente<T> {
    id? : number;
    pessoa?: T;
}

let c : Cliente<PessoaFisica> = new Cliente();
c.pessoa = new PessoaFisica();
c.pessoa.cpf = "123";
```

Veja [funcionando no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/klbosfll-maniero). E [no **TS Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCgU3Qe2AQG8AoBchASwBMB+ALgQDsBXAWxGygG4yKm8bbAwSQolJgHNeAXxIkUaDDnzAAYpTCVYhbAA8I2JtWW4wBYn3IAHFiGTak1gGa0EjMROlWEt+46hJNw9oL14KXzsHWFF9PGDRUKlwij9o3yg8Z00wYHj3RPFknzTHamAIYAB9JjRYSiEmCHzGABEK7Hk5BVR0LDMCACkWcWptXQMjE37VSwjSmJgALzyAZTx64GQEz2L5qMdYJmsAKx2k733-GMphAt3L1IObtnOi727FPoBhByNDAA8ABUAHxzCg0BKsDhcFI2AagZB3RgqczAOG+BEJIEY6wIgBMCVRBA0Wh0CAAPjM0cNRuMSN0kYgYoxfrcmtgAcT1JpxmCALzMbAAdwQbP+2AAFABKXiwAB0eNU9mwCEFTBF1JJvJ0Mt4TIQejVSEVCJVCDQWp5ZPRJD08tgLmNACIAIz4gDMzrlptm6s13NJ4z1Cl9aIdTsFbs93tDSrR+ONGtFgZ1wBDCvjBAjzhd7q9vBIAHoiwALCAQaxgegl6wQeWQOAAazwADcuM5kHhhQ7BEWAI5FgAsAFZXQBOABsAHYi66AAyuoA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/MultipleEntity.ts).

Ter que criar o objeto da pessoa na mão assim é um enorme vazamento de abstração. Uma das coisas que precisaria mudar é ter [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) do objeto.

## Dois tipos de cliente

Outra possibilidade é criar uma classe que seja `ClienteFisica` e outro tipo `ClienteJuridica`, mas não acho que seja melhor que a versão genérica, a não ser que as operações de cada um seja muito diferente. Para tomar a decisão correta precisa conceituar tudo direito. Sem saber para onde quer ir, qualquer lugar serve. Isso pode trazer vários problemas em outros pontos, mas não quero descartar nada.

## Aceitar a dinamicidade do dado

Mais uma possibilidade é usar o tipo `any` ali. Desta forma tudo seria acessível, porém está programando em JavaScript e não TypeScript. Por que adotar uma linguagem se vai usar recursos para contorná-la? Tem caso para usar, mas quase sempre é abuso. Fazendo isso tudo seria acessível, até o que não pode acessar.

## Tipo em união

Uma outra forma que vejo possível que é um pouco melhor mas sofre do problema do `any`, em menor grau. Pode usar um *union type*, algo assim:

```
pessoa? : PessoaFisica | PessoaJuridica;
```

O problema é que se criar uma pessoa física e tentar acessar um CNPJ o código aceitará, mas na execução quebrará. É uma solução, mas te obriga ser cuidado o tempo todo.

## Sem herança

Uma alternativa seria não fazer a herança. Não estou dizendo que é bom sempre, mas poderia ter só a `Pessoa` e não diferenciar se é física ou jurídica. Já que você tem tantos membros anuláveis, coloca os membros de ambos no mesmo objeto e só preenche uma parte dos membros dependendo do tipo de pessoa é, o que deve ter um campo para isso. Claro que você não poderá acessar todos os campos sempre porque alguns não estarão preenchidos, é igual ao *union type*, mas aqui vai consumir mais espaço, apesar de simplificar por ter apenas um tipo. Pode fazer sentido porque em muitos casos o tipo da pessoa é só um detalhe. Se fizer boas abstrações não terá que lidar com isso no consumo. E uma alternativa é ter objetos auxiliares só para manter os dados que variam de acordo com o tipo, assim não precisa ter campos nulos.

## Outras questões

Por que tem classe que preferiu explicitar a visibilidade pública e outras preferiu deixar o *default*?

Por que uma pessoa tem `nome`? Todas tem? Ok, pose ser, mas por que `PessoaJuridica` tem `razaoSocial`? Não é o mesmo que o nome? Se não é, precisaria justificar.

Desenvolver software não é só codificar, é pensar corretamente sobre o problema. Não pense que listei todos os problemas desse código.

Pode pensar o que isso te ma ver com o foco da pergunta. Quando conceitua certo talvez nem tenha esse problema.

Legal que montou a herança e composição do jeito certo, poucas pessoas fazem isso. Ou quase. Não é que esteja errado, mas pode inverter a questão. Se o principal for a pessoa e o cliente for considerado um dado secundário para a pessoa, isso pode ficar melhor. E aí faria sentido ter vários campos de [papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101) porque a pessoa pode realmente ter [vários papéis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313990/101). Não estou afirmando nada, depende do que precisa.

Tudo são alternativas. Não sei qual é melhor para você.

Comment: você abriu muito meu horizonte de ideias e me ajudou até mesmo com outros problemas em outras modelagens. Estudando um pouco mais afundo o typescript encontrei a ferramenta typeguards que poderia ajudar nesse caso. 
`let documento:string = (c.pessoa.isPessoaFisica()) ? c.pessoa.cpf : c.pessoa.cnpj`

Comment: `public isPessoaFisica() : this is PessoaFisica{
        return 'cpf' in this;
    }`

Comment: @MarcosLibanori eu estava pensando se TS tinha algo do tipo e achei até que tinha por ter sido criado pelo Anders, essa parece ser uma forma viável sim, mas ainda pode ter um problema de modelagem, como eu disse, depende do caso. No fundo o que ele está fazendo é um *cast* de forma assegurada. Não sei se precisa ser tão complexo assim, eu acho que não, pelo menos deveria poder ser mais simples.