# Como posso aceder a um método da subclass através de um objeto do tipo da superclass

Tags: java, cast, polimorfismo

Tendo uma super classe ABC

```
public class  ABC  { 
     int x = 0;   
    public int getABC() {  
        return x;
    }  
}

public class XYZ extends ABC  { 
     int y = 0;   
    public int getXYZ() {  
        return y;
    }  
}
```

Instanciando um objeto ABC com a sub classe XYZ assim:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
     ABC obj = new XYZ();
}
```

Como acedo ao método `getXYZ()`?

```
obj.getXYZ();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de fazer o cast para a `sub class`:

```
((XYZ) obj).getXYZ();
```

Answer (score 4):

Essencialmente você não deve fazer isso. É uma pena que em um exemplo artificial até compense fazer e pareça certo.

Se quiser fazer mesmo assim deve realizar um *cast* para fazer com que o tipo do objeto mude:

```
class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ABC obj = new XYZ();
        System.out.println(((XYZ) obj).getXYZ());
    }
}

class  ABC  { 
    int x = 0;   
    public int getABC() {  
        return x;
    }  
}

class XYZ extends ABC  { 
    int y = 0;   
    public int getXYZ() {  
        return y;
    }  
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R20451). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rjsabfya-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/CastPolymorphism.java).

Quando você diz que um objeto é de um determinado tipo o compilador só deixa o código acessar os membros daquele tipo, portanto só deixa acessar os membros de `ABC` neste caso. Como o objeto concreto é `XYZ` e tem outros membros você poderia acessá-los se o compilador deixar. Para fazer o compilador deixar tem que dizer que quer acessar esse objeto pelo tipo concreto e usa-se o *cast* para isso.

Porém se fizer isso provavelmente tem algo errado na modelagem. Se quer acessar o objeto concreto então porque declarou como objeto abstrato? Quando a declaração usa o supertipo é porque só fará operações em cima do que o supertipo permite, você está garantindo que não precisa de membros dos subtipos.

Isso pode ser feito e em alguns casos pode ser útil, mas ainda é um erro conceitual.

Mesmo em um caso concreto realista (que vai além de um exercício de um mecanismo individual) não é simples assim fazer isso. Em códigos reais você correrá o risco de ter outros subtipos daquele tipo e que não contenha o membro que está usando e sua aplicação quebrará, então tem que certificar que é do subtipo que espera ser para garantir que funcione. Obviamente nesse código exemplo não precisa fazer isso, está óbvio que é do subtipo correto, mas esse código não existe em aplicações reais. E se existir está fazendo algo muito errado, não faz sentido.

É legal aprender o mecanismo usado, mas se não souber como aplicá-lo corretamente programará errado. Procure um código real onde esse tipo de mecanismo pode ser realmente útil. Em modelagens corretas quase nunca é útil. Recentemente eu [respondi em outra linguagem onde era útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451967/101), mesmo assim não era o ideal e seria melhor ter outra solução.

Answer (score 0):

Quando o comando new foi executado, você gerou uma instância (um objeto) do tipo XYZ.
Entretanto, a sua referência, obj, é do tipo ABC. Sem problemas.

Para acessar os métodos de XYZ você precisa indicar que apesar de ter uma referência XYZ, esta está apontando para um objeto ABC.

O cast faz este papel:
((XYZ) obj).getXYZ()

Pensando no bom uso do polimorfismo, o melhor seria que de forma transparente, isto é, sem a necessidade se conhecer o tipo objeto obj.

```
public class  ABC  { 
    int x = 0;   
    public int get() {  
        return x;
    }  
}

public class XYZ extends ABC  { 
     int y = 0;   
    public int get() {  
        return y;
    }  
}

public class XPTO extends ABC  { 
     int z = 0;   
    public int get() {  
        return z;
    }  
}

...

obj.get();  // Você não se importa sobre qual classe obj instanciou
```