# Organização da memória quando há herança

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, memória, herança

Quando eu declaro `funcionario` como `Pessoa` no `main()`, para onde "vai" o valor do atributo `salario`, já que a classe `Pessoa` não tem esse atributo?

```
public abstract class Pessoa {

    private String nome;
    private Long cpf;

    public Pessoa(String nome, Long cpf) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
}




public class Funcionario extends Pessoa {

    private float salario;

    public Funcionario(String nome, Long cpf, float salario) {
        super(nome, cpf);
        this.salario = salario;
    }
}



public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pessoa funcionario = new Funcionario("Fulano", 123L, 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Nesse caso você tem um erro conceitual. A classe Funcionario é uma especialização da classe Pessoa. Isso significa que a classe Funcionario poderá e normalmente deverá ter atributos e métodos que são específicas dela. É o caso do Salário. Caso vocÊ precise deste valor. VocÊ deverá instanciar um objeto da classe Funcionário e utilizar uma variável do tipo Funcionario. Apesar de vocÊ ter criado uma instância de Funcionario você utilizou uma variavel do tipo Pessoa para o objeto criado. Desta forma, a variável funcionário só reconhecerá o que faz parte da definição de Pessoa.

```
public class Principal {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario("Fulano", 123L, 1000);
  }
}
```

Quando você faz  Pessoa funcionario = new Funcionario("Fulano", 123L, 1000); a variável funcionario  só irá reconhecer o que faz parte de Pessoa. Embora na memória exista o atributo Salário.

Um bom teste é você fazer o CAST para verificar isso

```
Funcionario f = (Funionario) funcionario;
System.out.println(f.getSalario());
```

**OBS> Crie um método getSalario na classe Funcionario para poder verificar o valor.**

Comment: Nesse caso, a instância é da classe Funcionario, mas como o tipo da variável é Pessoa, não tem como acessar o atributo salário?

Comment: Você só poderá ter acesso aos atributos e métodos que neste caso são definidos na Super Classe  - que neste caso é Pessoa. Faça o teste do cast e verifique. O atributo salario não estará acessível para a variável do tipo Pessoa.

Comment: Fiz o teste e verifiquei que ocorre isso mesmo. Não sei se entendi bem a parte "Caso vocÊ precise deste valor. VocÊ deverá instanciar um objeto da classe Funcionário e não da classe Pessoa.". O objeto funcionario já não é uma instância da classe Funcionario?

Comment: Você está correto. Eu me confundi. Você deve utilizar uma variável do tipo Funcionario. A instância já é do Tipo Funcionario.

Answer (score 5):

Existe o [objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101) e existe a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101). Existem [tipos que são por valor e tipos que são por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Nos tipos por valor o objeto é colocado no local da variável, e os tipos por referência eles ficam em outro local (tipicamente o *heap*) e na variável vai a referência para este objeto.

Quando você cria uma instância de uma classe, portanto cria um objeto, de um tipo, através do construtor da classe e o `new`, você está alocando espaço na memória para o objeto da classe sendo criada e inicializando os valores desse objeto. è isso que terá na memória, um objeto da classe indicada no construtor. Então é aí que vão os campos ([não chama atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), lamento que quase todo mundo aprende errado) da classe `Funcionario`, que são os campos das classes que ele herda mais os campos declarados na própria classe.

O fato de declarar variável como um tipo mais geral não muda o *layout* de memória da classe senso instanciada, tudo está lá. Apenas a referência para o objeto considera que o tipo é mais geral, no caso `Pessoa`, mas o objeto está integral.

O compilador não deixa você acessar os campos exclusivos da classe `Funcionario` pela variável `funcionario` porque se diz que ela é de um tipo que não tem esses campos, mesmo que concretamente eles estejam lá. Nada impede você acessar os campos desse mesmo objeto através de uma outra variável que seja do tipo mais especializado, fazendo um *cast*.

Outro erro comum é fazer justamente essa herança. O grosso dos problemas que as pessoas cometem em orientação a objeto é com exemplos artificiais ou que sempre foram ensinados de forma errada. Por isso é preciso ser questionador e entender porque é assim e não apenas aceitar que alguém disse que é assim. Veja mais em [Funcionário pode ser papel de Pessoa Física?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313990/101).

Existem outros problemas nesse código, mas não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: nesse caso, Pessoa e Funcionário são tipos por referência ?

Comment: Sim, todas classes são.